# I don't want python print specified name in python

Tags: python

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange"]

for i in fruits:
    print(1*i)
```

So here I don't want python print apple fruit I want him only print grape and orange fruits

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is exactly. How is Python to know from your code that `grape` and `orange` should be printed, but `apple` should not? Are you asking how to skip the first element of a list when looping over it? (by the way, the `1*` part here is entirely superfluous - it works, but you don't need to tell Python to print something once every time you print something)

Comment: Are you looking for `if i != 'apple':`?

Comment: Or perhaps: `for i in fruits[1:]: print(i)`

Comment: You can do it like `for i in fruits[1:]:`

Comment: Or even just `print(*fruits[1:], sep='\n')`.

Comment: You could write some examples of inputs and outputs to help us to understand your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have sure if it's really what do you like to do:

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange"]

# list of string you dont want to print
dont_print = ["apple"]

for i in fruits:
    if i not in dont_print:
        print(1*i)
```

I used a list exceptions but there are other ways to.

Comment: Multiplying a string by `1` does effectively nothing. There's no need to duplicate that oddity here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all but the first element in a list, you can use a list slice to specify everything in the list from index `1` onward to the end of the list.

```
for i in fruits[1:]:
    print(i)
```

You can also simply expand the slice into print, and specify the separator as a newline.

```
print(*fruits[1:], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` to select cases that you don't want to print. Like this:

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange"]

for i in fruits:
    if i == "apple":
         continue
    else:
        print(i)
```

If you want to include another rules you can use the logical operator `in`. Like this:

```
fruits = ["apple", "grape", "orange"]
remove_fruits = ["apple", "banana"]

for i in fruits:
    if i in remove_fruits:
         continue
    else:
        print(i)
```